# perl routing to get form values stopped working

Tags: forms, perl

I use some routines to get form data from a web form.
The program lives in /var/www/cgi-bin on a linux server.
I went from perl 5.10.1 to 5.22.1 and now the code below stopped working.
It gives me this error:
Use of uninitialized value in read for the third line from the top.
I can't figure out the problem.

```
sub populatePostFields {
 %postFields = ();
 read( STDIN, $tmpStr, $ENV{ "CONTENT_LENGTH" } );
 @parts = split( /\&/, $tmpStr );
 foreach $part (@parts) {
  ( $name, $value ) = split( /\=/, $part );
  $value =~ ( s/%23/\#/g );
  $value =~ ( s/%2F/\//g );
  $postFields{ "$name" } = $value;
 }
}

sub populateQueryFields {
%queryString = ();
my $tmpStr = $ENV{ "QUERY_STRING" };
@parts = split( /\&/, $tmpStr );
foreach $part (@parts) {
( $name, $value ) = split( /\=/, $part );
$queryString{ "$name" } = $value;
}
}

populatePostFields();
$strCode = $postFields{ "code" };
$strMode = $postFields{ "mode" };
$strUser = $postFields{ "loginName" };

if ($strCode ne "secretcode") {
 populateQueryFields();
 $strCode = $queryString{ "code" };
 $strMode = $queryString{ "mode" };
 $strUser = $queryString{ "loginName" };
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That means that `$ENV{ "CONTENT_LENGTH" }` is undefined. Any reason to believe it shouldn't be? /// Why reinvent the wheel (so extremely poorly)? Use the CGI module or something!!!

Comment: You're right ... I am no longer able to pass form data to programs in cgi-bin ... so I have another problem somewhere.